# What is the best way to manage a large quantity of constants

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am currently working on a very complex program that processes rows from an input table and has a huge number of possible outcomes for each record.  Because of this I have a very large number of constants defined for the outcome messages.  There is one success message for the record, but a multitude of possible warnings and errors.

My first thought was to define all of my constants for these messages at the package body level, but then I decided to move each constant to the procedure where it is used.  I'm now second guessing that decision and thinking of moving everything back to package body level.  What is the best way to define this many constants? Ease of maintainability is my ultimate goal for this program since it is so complex.

Comment: Personally if there were a lot of outcome messages I'd *consider* putting them in a lookup table instead. That way I have the option of using an efficient query to get them all in one gulp, instead of doing lots of if/then/else or case statements in the procedural code. But YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a matter of taste. In my application I put all error codes into an Error-Package. All main and commonly used constants I put into a separate package (without a package body).

Answer (score 3):

Again, a matter of taste, but I tend to put a list of named constants at the package spec level rather than the package body so that they can be referenced by any portion of the application. If I ever want to change the error code that c_err_for_specific_reason_x uses, it becomes a single place to do so.

If I wanted to hide the codes and put them within the body I would have a get_error_code(p_get_error_name varchar) function that did the translation based on you passing a valid constant name.

I've done both on different projects, but tend towards the list over the function most times. I tend to use the function if it a table-driven source of the data.

Answer (score 0):

It ... wait for it ... depends!

Since you currently define your constants in the package body, you don't need them to be publicly accessible outside the package. So defining them in a spec really doesn't buy you anything.

Here's is the rule I follow: Define constants within the smallest scope needed. So if a constant is used only within one procedure, define it in that procedure. If it is used within more than one procedure, define it in the body. If it is used elsewhere by code in other packages (or non-packaged SPs) but only when using a particular package, define it in the spec of that package. If it is used by other code for general use, put it in a separate spec of such general constants.